# What happens with simultaneous scp and mv?

Tags: filesystems, scp, mv

What happens when I `scp` large file from computer `A` to computer `B`, then move `mv` that file to a different location on the same partition of computer `B` before the `scp` is complete?

I assume just the location is updated in the directory entry? So my file will not be corrupted in any way by doing so?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, assuming the target where the file is moved to is on same file system moving the file will only update directory entries. Moving a file won't alter the file descriptor which `scp` uses to write the file on `B` <sup><sup>[note]</sup></sup>.

On different filesystems `mv` has to copy the file first, and then unlink the file at old location. The only situation you could see corruption is if you move to different filesystem before transfer is complete (`scp` has not received everything/flushed write buffers before `mv`). Then it is possible `mv` might copy the file only partially, resulting in corrupted copy.

<sup>[note]: if `scp` tranfer was interrupted, obviously it could not be resumed using the original path if the file was moved.</sup>

Comment: Hmm … if `scp` has `open`ed the file, then unlinking it will not delete it until `scp` has closed the file. `open`ing a file and then immediately `unlink`ing it is a common trick to implement "reasonably safe" tempfiles. (I say reasonably safe because there is a race condition window in between `open`ing and `unlink`ing the file, where an attacker could observe and / or alter the file.) This trick wouldn't work if `unlink`ing the file deleted or corrupted it.

Comment: Indeed as the file which `scp` writes to isn't modified. The copy at target might however be corrupted/incomplete (because all data was not written yet).

Comment: How? If you `unlink` the file while `scp` has it `open`, literally *nothing* will happen to the file. It will only be deleted *after* `scp` has closed it.

Comment: I'm talking about the *copy* on new filesystem, not the file `scp` has opened. If the file is not completely received, the copy can not be complete.

Comment: @sebasth Why do you think the file would not be completely received? While `scp` has an open file descriptor the it can still read and send the entire contents ever if you have unlinked the file.

Comment: @DougO'Neal `scp` will complete without errors, but if the file was copied and unlinked by `mv` before `scp` has completed, the copy will not be not complete.

Comment: @sebasth The copy will be complete. The file is never unlinked completely if any process has an open file descriptor on it. For example, look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028874/what-happens-to-an-open-file-handle-on-linux-if-the-pointed-file-gets-moved-del). The only time you would have a problem is if you re-wrote the file during the copy.

Comment: @DougO'Neal how can it be complete if `mv` exits (long) before `scp` does? `scp` will keep receiving/sending more data, similarly `mv` will read the same file, to which `scp` writes to, copies it until `EOF` and then `unlink`. The copy is incomplete if `scp`has not finished.